# Is there a word for when caravan guards kill a merchant and take all his stuff to sell? Other than defalcator?

Tags: synonyms

If it was on sea it would be mutineer. I swear there is a word for this.

Comment: Entrepreneur? :D

Comment: @Roger Here's hoping we never go into business together!

Comment: I assume by 'caravan' you mean the kind with camels; and not the one that is towed by a car on wheels.

Comment: @WS2 Nope. Modern merchants frequently hire guards to protect their trailers... :)

Comment: @WS2 Either way works honestly.

Comment: Liberators, maybe?

Comment: Are you sure it's an English word? Perhaps nomads have 1000 words for 'mutineer'. Incidentally, 'mutineer' would work; the most general definition needs neither a military nor a maritime connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Hijack](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hijack)** (*hijacker*):

> 1. to steal (cargo) from a truck or other vehicle after forcing it to stop: (to hijack a load of whiskey.)
> 2. to rob (a vehicle) after forcing it to stop: (They hijacked the truck before it entered the city.)
> 3. to seize (a vehicle) by force or threat of force.

Just as mutiny doesn't necessarily involve murder, neither does hijacking.

**[Inside job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inside_job)** is a crime committed by a person with a position of trust with trusted access or the freedom to operate within the enterprise. The *insider* may be a key employee or manager or may have been one recently.

**[Rogue](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rogue)** or **[renegade](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/renegade)** would be a noun that describes the insider who turns against his employer:

> no longer obedient, belonging, or accepted and hence not controllable or answerable; deviating, renegade: (a rogue cop; a rogue union local.)

Comment: This may be the best option. The only problem is that the word  hijack implies theft from an external source instead of a betrayal.

Comment: You may infer that, but it ain't necessarily so. Pilots have been known to hijack their own (or their companies') airplanes, for example.

Comment: Pilots highjacking their own airplane may occur but generally, I'd think most people would assume that a highjacker was not a caravan guard, as @milestyle said.

Comment: You can combine these for additional clarity, as well: "The guards went rogue and hijacked the caravan."

Answer (score 1):

The guards might be *defectors.* But they could be engaging in an *impersonation* (perhaps of officers of the law?).